# How to hide selected option in custom select list?

Tags: jquery, select

I have a very nice custom select list code and its almost perfect, except for the shown option thats already selected. Could anyone help me to simply hide it? Like if 'car' is selected and you click on the select field again, it should not show 'car' in the list but all others. I need more text so I thank anyone in advance for your time.

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  enableSelectBoxes();
});

function enableSelectBoxes() {
  $('div.selectBox').each(function() {
    $(this).children('span.selected').html($(this).children('ul.selectOptions').children('li.selectOption:first').html());
    $('input.price_values').attr('value', $(this).children('ul.selectOptions').children('li.selectOption:first').attr('data-value'));

    $(this).children('span.selected,span.selectArrow').click(function() {
      if ($(this).parent().children('ul.selectOptions').css('display') == 'none') {
        $(this).parent().children('ul.selectOptions').css('display', 'block');
      } else {
        $(this).parent().children('ul.selectOptions').css('display', 'none');
      }
    });

    $(this).find('li.selectOption').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().css('display', 'none');
      $('input.price_values').attr('value', $(this).attr('data-value'));
      $(this).parent().siblings('span.selected').html($(this).html());
    });
  });
} //-->
```

```css
#dd01 {
  padding: 14px 5px 14px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

div.selectBox {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: default;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 40px;
  clear: both;
  color: rgb(114, 97, 97);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

span.selected {
  width: 100px;
  text-indent: 15px;
  border-right: none;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 40px !important;
  color: #4096ee;
}

span.selectArrow {
  width: 35px;
  height: 40px !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
}

span.selectArrow,
span.selected {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul.selectOptions {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 135px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none inside none;
  padding-left: 0;
  z-index: 55;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  color: #666 !important;
}

li.selectOption {
  display: block;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 12px 0px 12px 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

li.selectOption:hover {
  color: #f6f6f6;
  background: #4096ee;
}

.selectArrow img {
  width: 10px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.lc02 {
  border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dd01">
  <div class="filters">
    <div class="ui-group">
      <div class="selectBox button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="cat">
        <input type="hidden" value="3" class="price_values" />
        <span class='selected'></span>
        <span class='selectArrow'></span>
        <ul class="selectOptions">
          <li class="selectOption button lc03" data-filter=".apple">Apple</li>
          <li class="selectOption button" data-filter=".car">Car</li>
          <li class="selectOption button" data-filter=".fork">Fork</li>
          <li class="selectOption button" data-filter=".pink">Pink</li>
          <li class="selectOption button lc02" data-filter=".red">Red</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Iterate the Loop of your Options and get Value, match selected `addClass` and update your dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select any option, show all of the options and hide the one you selected.

Since the `li.selectOption` is `display: block`, you can simply use `.show()` to display them.

```
$(this).find('li.selectOption').click(function() {
    // show all the options
    $(this).siblings().show()
    // hide the one you selected
    $(this).hide()
    $(this).parent().css('display', 'none');
    $('input.price_values').attr('value', $(this).attr('data-value'));
    $(this).parent().siblings('span.selected').html($(this).html());
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  enableSelectBoxes();
  // after the select boxes are initialized, click the first option
  $('ul.selectOptions li.selectOption:first').click();
});

function enableSelectBoxes() {
  $('div.selectBox').each(function() {
    $(this).children('span.selected').html($(this).children('ul.selectOptions').children('li.selectOption:first').html());
    $('input.price_values').attr('value', $(this).children('ul.selectOptions').children('li.selectOption:first').attr('data-value'));

    $(this).children('span.selected,span.selectArrow').click(function() {
      if ($(this).parent().children('ul.selectOptions').css('display') == 'none') {
        $(this).parent().children('ul.selectOptions').css('display', 'block');
      } else {
        $(this).parent().children('ul.selectOptions').css('display', 'none');
      }
    });

    $(this).find('li.selectOption').click(function() {
      // show all the options
      $(this).siblings().show()
      // hide the one you selected
      $(this).hide()
      $(this).parent().css('display', 'none');
      $('input.price_values').attr('value', $(this).attr('data-value'));
      $(this).parent().siblings('span.selected').html($(this).html());
    });
  });
} //-->
```

```css
#dd01 {
  padding: 14px 5px 14px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

div.selectBox {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: default;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 40px;
  clear: both;
  color: rgb(114, 97, 97);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

span.selected {
  width: 100px;
  text-indent: 15px;
  border-right: none;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 40px !important;
  color: #4096ee;
}

span.selectArrow {
  width: 35px;
  height: 40px !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
}

span.selectArrow,
span.selected {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul.selectOptions {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 135px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none inside none;
  padding-left: 0;
  z-index: 55;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  color: #666 !important;
}

li.selectOption {
  display: block;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 12px 0px 12px 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

li.selectOption:hover {
  color: #f6f6f6;
  background: #4096ee;
}

.selectArrow img {
  width: 10px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.lc02 {
  border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dd01">
  <div class="filters">
    <div class="ui-group">
      <div class="selectBox button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="cat">
        <input type="hidden" value="3" class="price_values" />
        <span class='selected'></span>
        <span class='selectArrow'></span>
        <ul class="selectOptions">
          <li class="selectOption button lc03" data-filter=".apple">Apple</li>
          <li class="selectOption button" data-filter=".car">Car</li>
          <li class="selectOption button" data-filter=".fork">Fork</li>
          <li class="selectOption button" data-filter=".pink">Pink</li>
          <li class="selectOption button lc02" data-filter=".red">Red</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! this is simple and perfect. Im new to codes like this and tried my best but couldnt make this. really thank you

Comment: I see there is still 'apple' showing on the beginning. Is there a way to change it too? Like hide 'apple' from the beginning? I need the already selected category from the beginning.

Comment: You can simulate `click()` at the beginning using `$('ul.selectOptions li.selectOption:first').click();`. I added it to the snippet.